# Getting specific event version via Event Message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

We are trying to show all the event details about an event message, we are tracking multiple messages, some are `eventMessage`.
When trying to access the event relationship on the `eventMessage` we always get the same event for all messages in the conversation.

Therefore, the original event message shows the latest event properties (start and end time, location, etc.)

I've tried to use the Microsoft Graph Explorer to see if there is any way to get a specific event item by using the `changeKey` of the item itself.
Sadly, with no success.

For example, when trying to access all messages within a conversation by filtering with the conversation id and expanding the event relationship

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/?$filter=conversationId eq '<ConversationId>='&$expand=Microsoft.Graph.EventMessage/Event
```

We always get the same event for all messages.

```
{    
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessage",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"<CHANGEKEY1>\"",
            "id": "<MSGID1>",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-05-26T15:48:46Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-06-09T23:34:48Z",
            "changeKey": "<CHANGEKEY1>",
            "receivedDateTime": "2019-05-26T15:48:46Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2019-05-26T15:48:44Z",            
            "event": {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"<EVENTCHANGEKEY>\"",
                "id": "<EVENTID>",
                "createdDateTime": "2019-05-26T15:48:46.2276944Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-06-16T11:42:26.1599832Z",
                "changeKey": "<EVENTCHANGEKEY>",
                "categories": [],
                "originalStartTimeZone": "Israel Standard Time",
                "originalEndTimeZone": "Israel Standard Time",
                "iCalUId": "<ICALUID>",
                "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
                "isReminderOn": false,
                "hasAttachments": false,
                "importance": "normal",
                "sensitivity": "normal",
                "isAllDay": false,
                "isCancelled": false,
                "isOrganizer": false,
                "responseRequested": true,
                "seriesMasterId": null,
                "showAs": "tentative",
                "type": "singleInstance",
                "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
                "recurrence": null,
                "responseStatus": {
                    "response": "notResponded",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-06-11T09:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-06-11T09:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "location": {
                    "displayName": "טלפוני / במשרד",
                    "locationType": "default",
                    "uniqueId": "ff8323c6-c525-415a-be80-88de9c1bd53d",
                    "uniqueIdType": "locationStore"
                },
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "displayName": "טלפוני / במשרד",
                        "locationType": "default",
                        "uniqueId": "ff8323c6-c525-415a-be80-88de9c1bd53d",
                        "uniqueIdType": "locationStore"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessage",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"<CHANGEKEY2>\"",            
            "id": "<MSGID2>",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-06-09T23:34:46Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-06-17T10:00:07Z",
            "changeKey": "<CHANGEKEY2>",
            "receivedDateTime": "2019-06-09T23:34:47Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2019-06-09T23:34:45Z",
            "event": {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"<EVENTCHANGEKEY>\"",
                "id": "<EVENTID>",
                "createdDateTime": "2019-05-26T15:48:46.2276944Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-06-16T11:42:26.1599832Z",
                "changeKey": "<EVENTCHANGEKEY>",
                "categories": [],
                "originalStartTimeZone": "Israel Standard Time",
                "originalEndTimeZone": "Israel Standard Time",
                "iCalUId": "<ICALUID>",
                "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
                "isReminderOn": false,
                "hasAttachments": false,
                "importance": "normal",
                "sensitivity": "normal",
                "isAllDay": false,
                "isCancelled": false,
                "isOrganizer": false,
                "responseRequested": true,
                "seriesMasterId": null,
                "showAs": "tentative",
                "type": "singleInstance",
                "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
                "recurrence": null,
                "responseStatus": {
                    "response": "notResponded",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },                
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-06-11T09:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-06-11T09:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "location": {
                    "displayName": "טלפוני / במשרד",
                    "locationType": "default",
                    "uniqueId": "ff8323c6-c525-415a-be80-88de9c1bd53d",
                    "uniqueIdType": "locationStore"
                },
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "displayName": "טלפוני / במשרד",
                        "locationType": "default",
                        "uniqueId": "ff8323c6-c525-415a-be80-88de9c1bd53d",
                        "uniqueIdType": "locationStore"
                    }
                ]
                }
            }           
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABQAAAC5VJWM6fuTTIIUqGiAHWMQAAEwug==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADliYjE5MWViLWNlMGQtNDliYy05YThkLWM4YWZiNzY2ODdlNwBGAAAAAAA5_Z03NIx3SqoeFwQnhSEiBwDt8lpmQG0nRYbMU6WI2FVeAAAAAAEPAADt8lpmQG0nRYbMU6WI2FVeAAFkUv4FAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-06-17T10:31:28Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-06-17T10:28:24Z",
            "changeKey": "CQAAABQAAAC5VJWM6fuTTIIUqGiAHWMQAAEwug==",
            "categories": [],
            "receivedDateTime": "2019-06-17T10:31:26Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2019-06-17T10:31:30Z",
            "hasAttachments": true,
            "internetMessageId": "<DB7PR03MB39784FB9DE2927C185428518CFEB0@DB7PR03MB3978.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com>",
            "subject": "FW: Recruitment briefing before 8200 conference  ",
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "importance": "normal",
            "parentFolderId": "AAMkADliYjE5MWViLWNlMGQtNDliYy05YThkLWM4YWZiNzY2ODdlNwAuAAAAAAA5_Z03NIx3SqoeFwQnhSEiAQDt8lpmQG0nRYbMU6WI2FVeAAAAAAEPAAA=",
            "conversationId": "<ConversationId>=",
            "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
            "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
            "isRead": false,
            "isDraft": true,
            "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADliYjE5MWViLWNlMGQtNDliYy05YThkLWM4YWZiNzY2ODdlNwBGAAAAAAA5%2BZ03NIx3SqoeFwQnhSEiBwDt8lpmQG0nRYbMU6WI2FVeAAAAAAEPAADt8lpmQG0nRYbMU6WI2FVeAAFkUv4FAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
            "inferenceClassification": "focused",            
            "toRecipients": [],
            "ccRecipients": [],
            "bccRecipients": [],
            "replyTo": [],
            "flag": {
                "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We expected to get each eventMessage with its own "version" of the event itself.
In the provided case, the start and end time should have been changed.
When accessing the `webUrl` property, we get the expected result.

As shown in the web url:

**Original Message**

[image: Image from Gyazo]

**Updated Message**

[image: Image from Gyazo]